# How can I easily indent header declarations with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, indentation

I like for my c++ member variables and method declarations to all be indented by the same amount, so that they line up like this:

```
class SnipformationScheduler : public ParagraphformationFinishedResponder
{
    int                                         mCurrentSnipIndex; 
    vector<ParagraphFormationAnimation>         mParagraphAnimations;
public:
    vector<string>                              mSnippetIDs;
    MovementController*                         mMovementController;

    SnipformationScheduler();
    virtual ~SnipformationScheduler(void);
    void                                        tick();
    void                                        paragraphAnimationFinished();
};
```

Currently, I do this by pressing tab until I get to the correct number of indentations. Surely there's an easier way. Anybody know what it is?

Comment: Just a comment: I always get terribly angry when people do this. It makes code totally unreadable for me, I need to scan this wast white space from right to left to find out what type is `mCurrentSnipIndex` for example.

Comment: I know of editors that will do this but VS isn't one of them.  Frankly, it's a terrible editor; its auto-formatting features are more of an annoyance than a help.

Comment: @aleguna: Sometimes you have no choice. Our coding conventions mandate that member variables must be aligned. Comparing with the question our differences are: - function names are not aligned; - only members within the same block must be aligned; - alignment is mandated by the longest type (i.e. no random number of extra spaces between the longest name and the variable) - pointers are right aligned together with the name of the variable. If you are in a company with a set of rules, you must play by those rules. You can check some of the code [here](https://github.com/bloomberg/bsl)

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there's an easier way. However, please uses spaces for alignment. Tabs, if you use them at all (some people have their editor set to enter several spaces when they hit the tab key), should be for indentation only.

The rationale behind this is that different people have tabs set to show up as a different number of spaces. If I use...

- All spaces, everyone always sees the same thing in their editor. However, they can't control the width of indentations (this annoys me personally).
- All tabs, people can set the width of the indentations, but things might not line up if other people use a different tab width than you.
- Tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment, everyone is happy. Everything always lines up, and people can set the width of their indentations.

Comment: Just to be precise, slavik262 means that TABs should only be used if they are the first characters in a line. Any whitespace after the first non-TAB character should be made with space characters, not TABs.